# Convert chr to ordered factor and set factor levels causing error

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` as R, as seen below, that includes the conditions "Used", "Certified pre-owned", and "New.  In my actual dataset, when I read in the dataset, this variable is loaded as a `chr`.  Using the `factor` function, I know how to convert a `chr` to a `factor`,but I want to maintain the order of the factor, and set "Used" as the baseline.

I'd tried everything that I can find, but I'm obviously missing something.  How do I correct convert a `chr` to a ordered factor and specify the order level?

```
# example df
df <- data.frame(condition = c('Certified pre-owned', 'Used', 'Used', 'Used', 'Used', 'Used', 'New', 'Used', 'Used'))

# show structure
str(df)

'data.frame':   9 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ condition: Factor w/ 3 levels "Certified pre-owned",..: 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3

# change order of conditoin
df$condition <- as.ordered(df$condition, levels=c("Used", "Certified pre-owned", "New"))

Error in as.ordered(df$condition, levels = c("Used", "Certified pre-owned", : unused argument (levels = c("Used", "Certified pre-owned", "New"))
Traceback:

1. as.ordered(df$condition, levels = c("Used", "Certified pre-owned", "New"))

# convert to factor, but without levels
df$condition <- as.ordered(factor(df$condition))

# but the order puts them in alphabetical order, which is not what I want
levels(df$condition)

'Certified pre-owned' 'New' 'Used'
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: My expected output is a ordered factor that is in the order that I want it to be and not alphabetical order.

Comment: `df$condition <- factor(df$condition, levels=c("Used", "Certified pre-owned", "New"), ordered=TRUE)`. However, note that the order of the factor is set by the order in which you list the levels, regardless of whether you include `ordered=TRUE`. You need `ordered=TRUE` only if you want this variable to behave as an ordinal variable in addition to being ordered the way you want.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 I appreciate it!